# Funding requirements when applying for a PLAB visa after a previous UK Standard Visitor visa rejection

Tags: visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK Standard Visitor visa a couple of months ago and was refused because I did not submit bank statements from the sponsor who had provided me with funds as pocket money/gift. Now, I have to apply for a PLAB visa in February, 2016. I intend to do that on the basis of my bank statements only with no help from a sponsor.

What I need to know is, will the ECO ask for proof of the origin of the previous funds or just consider the statements that I shall provide with my PLAB visa application?

Comment: I'm not sure if the answer to that question clarifies what expectations there are for submitted bank statements.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-provenance-of-funds