# UK visit visa refused twice

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I had applied twice for a UK visit visa in January for the purpose of sitting the PLAB 2 medical exam , but my applications were refused , though my cousin who is a consultant doctor in UK-NHS sponsored me for the visit.

The first refusal was because I didn't provide a bank statement, and the hotels that I booked were found to be cancelled ( I cancelled the bookings because my cousin advised to do so as he was more aware of better hotels ).

In the second application , I provided my bank statement. But however the application was refused again on the grounds that the statement contained only two transactions and didn't reflect my income and savings.

I am a doctor and live in Iraq . I receive my salary in cash like most governmental employees here. I have tried to make an active bank statement in the last 5 months with numerous cash transactions so that they can mimics my savings and expenditure.

I am looking forward to hearing assistance regarding this soon , it's really frustrating.

Kind regards

Refusal papers 1 & 2 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking how to prepare a document that mimics a bank statement? The portion of the refusal notice you uploaded (and thanks for that) indicates a provenance of funds issue. Is that part of your question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I couldn't upload the refusal paper of the second application. I would like to apply for a third time , how should I best prepare my application this time ? I already have a new bank statement that contains many transactions.

Comment: I can see the problem. I think your question is already answered; we have a fair number of PLAB refusals in the archives here which are still current and valuable. Please read them and see if they are helpful. I'll close this one as a duplicate until you can assess the material and see if there are significant differences that make your question unique. Ping me if you want your question reopened.

Comment: also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58654/applying-for-a-plab-visa-after-a-previous-uk-visit-visa-rejection

Comment: also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48380/uk-visa-bank-statement-info

Comment: I looked at them all , but no one resembled mine , especially regarding cancelling my hotel bookings

Comment: I don't think 4 - 5 minutes and a bit is sufficient to do that...  BUT... OK, click the button that says 'reopen' and the question will be examined, it should take not very long.

Comment: I looked at them months ago , after I got my refusals...

Comment: also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62441/uk-visa-hotel-booking-and-contact-information/62448#62448

Comment: Also related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/32134

Comment: Two of the scans are still illegible (too small) and I am not sure in what order they are. I am therefore voting to leave this question closed as you have not made it clear enough yet. However let me tell you one **good** advice: get a solicitor if you want to get in (it might be hard to get one). If you apply again without seeking professional help you are likely to attract another refusal which will further hurt your chances to get visa in the future. This is going to be costly but I am not convinced you have good chances when trying again on your own, I am sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You should never try "manipulating" your account because the UK visa Offices can see right through that.

Instead, you should get a written, notarised and translated confirmation from your employer stating your position, your income, **and the fact that you get it in cash.**

I agree it seems very strange that you're spending 5.6 times your monthly income for a 25-day trip. You should definitely explain that to the visa Office, and also explain why your Hotel booking was cancelled, preferably with a notarised statement from your cousin.

And in the future: **never** modify any travel plans until you have the visa in your passport